# I am trying to create a dash app for a Restaurant directory the dropdown filter is work I know but map doesn't update

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I have restaurant name, cusines, lat , long as columns. The map I am trying to show on the html page is not updating as per the filter , It shows all the restaurnats.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 


app = dash.Dash('app')

df = pd.read_excel('Resturants.XLSX')


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Resturant map by cusine', style={'text-align': 'center'} ),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='cusine_dd', 
                 options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.cusines.unique()],
                  value = 'Chinese',
                 style={'width':'40%'}),
    
    html.Div(id= 'output', children =[] ),

    dcc.Graph(id='mapbycusine', figure={})
])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    Output(component_id='mapbycusine', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='cusine_dd', component_property='value')]
)
def update_figure(input_cusine):
    #cusine_filter = 'All'
    container = f"Currently showing {input_cusine}"
    df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
    if input_cusine:
        df_copy = df_copy[df_copy['cusines'] == input_cusine]  
    print(df_copy.head())
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame=df_copy, lat='Latitude',  lon='Longitude', zoom=3, height=300, hover_data= ['cusines'])
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
    fig.update_layout(height=1000, margin={"r":100,"t":100,"l":100,"b":300})
    return container, fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am checking every step just to make sure if input and output is working I have used countainers updates on the html page and print the df_copy after filtering data as per the input cusine. The containers give the correct output and the df.copy.head() shows only filltered columns in the console but the map on html dash app is not updating.

I want the map to show the restaurants for just the selected cusine

Comment: Can you include a portion of the `df` so that we can reproduce your dash app and help you debug? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(15).to_dict()` directly into your question – thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error, but perhaps some of the steps I took in debugging might prove helpful:

First, I took the first 100 rows of [a restaurant dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/khushishahh/fast-food-restaurants-across-us?resource=download), and then randomly assigned three different cuisine types to each unique restaurant name. Then when creating the `fig` object with `px.scatter_mapbox`, I passed the cuisine column to the `color` argument and a mapping between cuisine and color to the `color_discrete_map` argument so that the marker colors will be different when you select different cuisine types from the dropdown.

This is the result, with visible changes between the marker locations as well as the marker colors (depending on the dropdown selection). Also, as you mentioned, the print outs of `df_copy` from inside your `update_figure` function match the dropdown selections as expected.

[image]

As far as I can tell, the only thing fundamentally different between your dashboard and mine would be the data that was used. Maybe it is possible that you have a bunch of duplicate rows that span multiple cuisines (i.e. imagine I took a data set of only Mexican restaurants, then duplicated all of the rows but switched the cuisine to Italian – then if you select Mexican or Italian from the dropdown, the result would be the same because you're plotting all of the same latitudes and longitudes in each case so the figure wouldn't appear to change, and you might not catch this from examining the `df_copy` print outs).

Can you verify that your data set doesn't contain duplicate latitude and longitude points with different cuisines assigned to the same point?

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 


app = dash.Dash('app')

# df = pd.read_excel('Resturants.XLSX')

## create a small restaurant dataset similar to yours
## downloaded from: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/khushishahh/fast-food-restaurants-across-us?resource=download
df = pd.read_csv('Fast_Food_Restaurants_US.csv', nrows=100, usecols=['latitude','longitude','name'])
df.rename(columns={'latitude':'Latitude', 'longitude':'Longitude'}, inplace=True)

## randomly assign some cuisine types to unique restaurant names
unique_names = df['name'].unique()
np.random.seed(42)
name_cuisine_map = {
    name:cuisine for name,cuisine in 
    zip(unique_names, np.random.choice(['American','Mexican','Chinese'], size=len(unique_names)))
}
cuisine_color_map = {
    'American':'blue',
    'Mexican':'green',
    'Chinese':'red'
}
df['cusines'] = df['name'].map(name_cuisine_map)
df['color'] = df['cusines'].map(cuisine_color_map)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Resturant map by cusine', style={'text-align': 'center'} ),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='cusine_dd', 
                 options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.cusines.unique()],
                  value = 'Chinese',
                 style={'width':'40%'}),
    
    html.Div(id= 'output', children =[] ),

    dcc.Graph(id='mapbycusine', figure={})
])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    Output(component_id='mapbycusine', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='cusine_dd', component_property='value')]
)
def update_figure(input_cusine):
    #cusine_filter = 'All'
    container = f"Currently showing {input_cusine}"
    df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)
    if input_cusine:
        df_copy = df_copy[df_copy['cusines'] == input_cusine]  
    print("\n")
    print(df_copy.head())
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame=df_copy, lat='Latitude',  lon='Longitude', zoom=3, height=300, hover_data= ['cusines'], color='cusines', color_discrete_map=cuisine_color_map)
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
    fig.update_layout(height=1000, margin={"r":100,"t":100,"l":100,"b":300})
    return container, fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I was able to resolve by passing input_cusine to a separate function and returning the fillered data set for the fuchtion and then use the return value for  px.scatter_mapbox data_frame. 
But it increased the line of code. Thanks :)

Comment: okay it sounds like it was indeed a data issue – your code for creating and updating the dropdowns were correct. i'm glad to have helped!